# How to subtract a cell in column 22 from a cell in column 24 in the same row on a change trigger using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The following script subtracts all rows in the sheet when the on change trigger executes. I require the script to only subtract the row on which the change is made.

````
  var sourceSpreadsheetID = '1r4e4BNKwsmdC2Ry93Mq-N49zj3DAZVpHG21TgTe0FWY' ;
  var sourceWorksheetName = "CONCRETE";
  
  var docketSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var docketsheet = docketSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var maxRows = docketsheet.getMaxRows();
  var loadRange = docketsheet.getRange(2, 22, maxRows);  
//row, column, number of rows
  var totalRange = docketsheet.getRange(2, 24, maxRows);
  
  var soldValues = loadRange.getValues();
  var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();
  for (var row in soldValues) {
  var soldCellData = soldValues[row][0];
  var totalCellData = totalValues[row][0];

  if (soldCellData !== "" && totalCellData !== "" ) {
  totalValues[row][0] = totalCellData - 
  soldCellData;
  
}
}
loadRange.setValues(soldValues);
totalRange.setValues(totalValues);
}```

Thanks, your assistance is greatly appreciated
````

Answer (score 2):

```
function myfunk() {
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1r4e4BNKwsmdC2Ry93Mq-N49zj3DAZVpHG21TgTe0FWY');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("CONCRETE");
  const drg = dsh.getRange(2, 22, dsh.getLastRow() - 1, 3);
  const vs = drg.getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (r[0] != '' && r[2] != '') {
      r[2] -= r[0];
    }
  });
  dsh.getRange(2, 22, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

one row at a time:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "CONCRETE" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 24) {
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 22, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 24).setValue(vs[2] - vs[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however unfortunately when the script is executed it subtracts the data for all the rows rather than only subtracting the row which is updated. For example when I change the value in the cell in row 3 column 22, I require this to be subtracted from the value in row 3 column 24 only. The code make the calculation on all the rows. I require the calculation to on 1 row at any time. I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Try the second version

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the second version. I might be missing something obvious but when I run the script I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'range' of undefined"?

Comment: It requires the trigger event object so you cannot run it from the script editor.  Just save it in the script editor and  go edit column 24 and greater the row 1 of the sheet concrete and the script will run.  If you have other functions named onEdit(e) it will not run if they are first in the list of files for your project.